# css list item same margin with all resolutions

Tags: css, list, margin, resolution

i'm trying to  make a menu, i want my menu looks like centered to left and right side of page in all resolutions. eg;

```
  800 width
       ----------------------------------------
      | menu item1    menu item2    menu item3 |
      |                                        |
       ----------------------------------------

  1920 width
       ------------------------------------------------
      |   menu item1       menu item2      menu item3  |
      |                                                |
       ------------------------------------------------
```

i've write a jquery function that calculates a new margin value for screen width and changes margin for every menu item. That works good. But i want to learn is it possible to do this only with css?

I also tried margin-left:5% but when screen has low width like 800, my menu items dont fit to div and some items go down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, the problem with the percentages is that they become very hard to work with when mixed with constants. You could probably make the items fit into the div by defining a % value for their font-sizes/paddings/line-heights as well.

On the other hand, if you only have 3 items in the menu, it would be easier to use float:left/right on item 1 and 3 and only change their margins based on the screen width. Ofcourse this probably wouldn't work on menus with more items.

Comment: so javascript function is better and easier?

Comment: it really depends on your design, if you're ok with #1 and #3 going to the far sides of the div (hence creating a big margin on each side of #2), you don't even need the JS. Just floating them would do the trick. But I wouldn't be. Also, you really don't need to manipulate the margins by JS. Just give a class to the body element about the screen width and define css based on that selector, like: "body.narrow .item" or "body.wide .item"